class name ='wrap_details' with border and without border
I have the same modal in a couple of places.
In one spot, it applies the border and in another spot, it does not apply the border. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Why does the border show up on the first screenshot and on the second it does not.

Here border is not shown


According to the styles inspector on the second screen, at the top of the inspector, there's a border-top: 0 style. So your modal is just placed in some block where additional styles overwrite the styles of the modal due to higher specificity.

@Invulner: But the black line is caused by a child component that is rendering. I do not want to change the child. Is there anything I can add before rendering that would cancel out the black border

You can override it as it's already done on the second screen. So create a style with any wrapper that will definitely wrap your modal wherever you need it. Even body .wrap_details will work.
